# Stack does not yet have a Debian package

Tags: ros, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to release executive_teer into unstable, but the build system does not create a debian package, for a reason I cannot explain. See for instance [this log](http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_unstable_executive_teer_lucid_i386/4/console).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30060/stack-does-not-yet-have-a-debian-package./) by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Debian packages actually have been greated (see [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-unstable-executive-teer/)). They are in the ros-shadow repository. It can take a while until the packages are moved from shadow to the main repository. I'm not sure though when they will be copied and what Willow's policy for copying is.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-20**:
Releasing into public is a manual sync which we do when there are enough differences to warrant a new release and all things expected to build have successfully built.  We don't push all the time that everything is built due to it triggering large downloads for the whole community.